# Escape "[" bracket from json

Tags: java, json

I know that "[" brackets are used in json to specify a list such as:
"Value":["A","B"]

However I want to use those brackets as is in json like "Value":"[A TO B]"
 since in the future this json string gets mapped to a URL:

I am using java where while using json parser it gives me an error.
Is there a way I can escape "[" brackets.

Comment: Post your code. Post the exact and complete error/stacktrace.

Comment: What json library are you using?

Comment: The brackets actually specify an array... see @ochi answer

Comment: Can you add more details about how you are doing the conversion and what library you are using?  So far, we may not have all the information needed to fully answer your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you keep it in quotes, it is valid JSON.  Try the code below in a [validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
{
    "key": "mykey",
    "Value": "[A TO B]"
}
```

It returns: valid!

Comment: How to escape a curly braces? "text {{ variable }} text"

Comment: @AamerShahzad what do you mean?  Same concept applies

Comment: Keep in mind too, your IDE may be showing that the string is screwed up even though in all actuality it is still valid json.  Test with something like https://jsonformatter.org/